# JavaScript object method returns null property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object, ecmascript-6, singleton

It is friday, so maybe I don't think clearly, but - I have following code:

```
var map = {
    myLatLng: null,
    init: function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            this.myLatLng = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
            console.log(this.myLatLng);
        });
    },
    drawRouteTo: function(destination){
        console.log(this.myLatLng);
    }
}
```

Than I use

```
map.init();
//and after some time - on click event
map.drawRouteTo("some address");
```

and the output is:

```
Object { lat: 50.0575, lng: 19.9802 }
null
```

Why is the second log returning null value? I should propably use classes and do not stick to the old patterns but I am still wondering why isn't it working.
Is it something wrong with the assigment itself ?

EDIT:
I have updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t1jdxmb8/1/
This should have fixed running this in scope of a callback but it does not work either

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t1jdxmb8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, `this` inside the `getCurrentPosition` points to window object instead of the map object.

Have a `reference`:

```
init: function(){
    var that = this;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        that.myLatLng = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
        console.log(that.myLatLng);
    });
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1jdxmb8/

Below is a working fiddle, a simulated one:

https://jsfiddle.net/t1jdxmb8/2/

Comment: Good point! I've updated my question with a fiddle, it is still not working properly

Comment: Yeah, thank You, I have to learn js more :| and stop asking dumb questions :v

Comment: Welcome, Trust yourself. You know more than you think you do.... everyone starts from zero and not 100... there is always area of improvement in everyone... we all keep learning... there is nothing wrong in asking questions...

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting `this.myLatLng` inside a callback function, you lose context to the objects's this property. Thus, you should store this variable into some local variable([closures in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)).

```js
var map = {
    myLatLng: null,
    init: function(){
    var that = this;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            that.myLatLng = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
            console.log(that.myLatLng);
        });
    },
    drawRouteTo: function(destination){
        console.log(this.myLatLng);
    }
}
```